# UINavigationBar: Change title size after rotate

Tags: iphone, ios5

I changed the font of the UINavigationBar title with the following code, in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:24.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

In portrait it is ok, but in landscape the font size is too big.
Is there a possibility to change the font size after rotating the device?

I think I could solve this with a custom titleView, but I am wondering if there is another option (without setting the size to a smaller number in portrait/in general :) )?

I am developing for iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your attributes using one of these two methods in the visible view controller to modify your code depending on what orientation the device is currently in. Your view controllers will need a pointer to the UINavigationController variable.

Method called right before view rotates:
`- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

Method called right after view rotates:

`- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`

More information on ViewController methods can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I would think the easiest way to accomplish this would be an if statement that sets the title attributes to one style if the device is verticle, else set to another because the device is horizontal.